# How can I be sure I am running the correct version of Flashplayer?

Tags: firefox, flash, plugins

My Firefox keeps reporting that I am running Flash 10.3, even though I am sure I installed 11.1.

[image: Example]

How can I know for sure which version I am running, and that I am running the correct version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution.
I previously had installed Adobe AIR, and I'm not sure, but it seems like the version of flash bundled with AIR was being pulled in. Since I don't use Adobe AIR for anything anymore, I removed this.

Either way, I ran:

`locate libflashplayer.so` and deleted every instance I found.

Then I purged Adobe-flashplugin and the control panel packages for gtk and kde (*just to be completely certain ;)*), and reinstalled them. Now Firefox is reporting the correct version.

Answer (score 3):

How did you install flash ? If from a repository you can check with

```
dpkg -l | grep flash
```

If from Adobe , what version is in the tar ?

You can also open firefox and type

```
about:plugins
```

If you wish to look at a lower level, I would use strace. strace dumps a fair amount of output to the terminal, so you can redirect it to a file with the -o option and reduce the output somewhat with the -e option.

```
sudo strace -o /tmp/firefox-trace.txt -e open /usr/bin/firefox
```

Open a flash video and you can grep the `/tmp/firefox-trace.txt` file to confirm the lib

```
grep flash /tmp/firefox-trace.txt
```

Comment: This is closer to a comment than an answer lol. I have tried the latter, and btw, I installed it from the repos.

Comment: Yea, but it shows the version , what are you needing ?

Comment: essentially to know that Firefox is pulling in the correct version and not using something from some custom directory for example.

Comment: I fixed it and gave you an upvote.

Comment: I suggest strace, I updated my answer

Comment: that's pretty useful (I know if strace but didn't know of that method).

Comment: I mean of in that last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the [flash check page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html) at adobe which will tell you the version of flash you are currently running

[image: reported flash version]

of course Firefox could be miss reporting to the Adobe site but I am sure the site actually checks the version of flash rather than the one reported by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you type `about:plugins` in the search-bar it will display the version of the flash library firefox uses

Comment: I had already looked here, after some deliberation over the source of the problem.